# Why can't I run Main.java on Eclipse "Errors exist in required project(s)"

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is error when I press run:

[image]

Down is Main.java and I don't know what this is. Yesterday I used this file and nothing happened.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LogIn.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700,512);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setTitle("Log In");
            Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sherr.jpeg"));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[Here is what displayed on Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EZCe.png)

Comment: there are still some errors to be resolved: what is being shown in the `Problems` view (`ALT-SHIFT-Q`,`X` or the left-most tab left of the console)

Comment: Specifically, problems in the *AutoSherretii* project, not the one with application you're trying to launch.

Comment: did you open console img, there u will see more, and problem doesnt solved, so i recreated same one,   and i used VM args,  user library, and mysql-connector, now is working good. THNX.

Comment: This isn't necessarily due to Problems. It could also be totally unrelated Eclipse download errors, as in my case (I went offline). No solution found yet.